# Async/Await Issue in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, async-await

On my Expo I am getting the following error:

[image]

I believe this is due to an Async/Await issue in my code, but I am unsure how to fix it. I am new to ReactNative, and am doing the Complete React Course by Stephen, but he does not discuss this issue at all so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import yelp from '/Users/macbook/Coding Stuff React Native/food/src/api/yelp.js'

export default () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const searchApi = async searchTerm => {
    console.log('Hi there!');
    try {
      const response = await yelp.get('/search', {
        params: {
          limit: 50,
          term: searchTerm,
          location: 'san jose'
        }
      });
      setResults(response.data.businesses);
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage('Something went wrong');
    }

  };

  // Call searchApi when component
  // is first rendered.  BAD CODE!
  // searchApi('pasta');
  useEffect(() => {
    searchApi('pasta');
  }, [])

  return [searchApi, results, errorMessage];
};
```

Thank you :)

Comment: `const response = async ....;` means that `response` is going to be a `Promise`.

Comment: Yes, I had seen this online. Is there a fix for the code to use this? Thanks for the response btw!

Comment: You would need to do your logic in `response.then(() => { ... })` which would execute once the promise has resolved.

Comment: I believe the issue isn't in this part of the code. Unlike react the strings in react native have to be rendered inside a <Text> tag only.

Comment: Can you add some more code where you have used this ?

Comment: you are mixing up a react component vs a function. if you are going to use react hooks, you need to return some sort of UI component, not [searchApi... etc..]. if you want to use this as a function, you can't use react hooks.

Comment: My instructor (stephen grider complete react native course) used this code and worked fine for him. It was also working fine for me, until today when i tried to re-run it and this happened :/

Comment: Taplar I will give this a go - thanks. Dipansh: How does this explain my expo suggesting it is this part of the code? Thanks! And Wen: My instructor used this code and it worked fine for him - this is why I am so confused!

Comment: @Taplar I tried this as so:  ```response.then(() => {useEffect(() => {
    searchApi('pasta');
  }, [])})

  return [searchApi, results, errorMessage];
};  `````  and got an error saying 'can't find variable 'response''. Am i putting it in the wrong place? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update for anyone else stuck on this:

I needed to change

```
{errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
```

to

```
{!!errorMessage && <Text>{errorMessage}</Text>}
```

Comment: Do you have some explanation why this fixed your problem?

Comment: I do not. I think maybe it is because when i called this const in another file, the searchApi wasn't finishing fast enough, and so it was reading {errorMessage} as a string because it had not been made in to a function in time. Doing this makes it a ternary expression, but i'm not sure why that helps. I'm new to ReactNative.